# Why plural noun and verb in singular form, present tense takes 's'?

Tags: verb-agreement

Acting in reverse manner, plural noun takes ‘s’ (apples, chalks) while verb in singular form, present tense takes ‘s’ (she prefers, he attends). Why is it so?

Wrote [Miss syndrome](http://www.sdsolutions.firm.in/2016/07/miss-syndrome.html) under Creative Writing category sometime back which not sure keep live.

*Acting in reverse manner, plural noun takes ‘s’ (apples, chalks) while verb in singular form, present tense takes ‘s’ (she prefers, he attends). Miss acts both as noun and verb. Miss as verb means something not attained like X misses Y while on vacation. Subject to Y being female, this can be rewritten: X misses Miss Y where capital Miss is noun (abbreviated as Ms.).
When hit is excess, reverse rule comes into action in behavior so often like a cool character converting to earthquake-like personality after a period of stress. Missing your favorite miss can overwhelmingly redefine your perception where anything you could not hold is a miss, be it catch miss, goal miss…*

So, should I immediately remove the above or the writing makes some sense?

Comment: The two "suffixes" have [completely different origins](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-s), so there isn't really a concept of ***Why?*** in the first place - the third person singular ***verb*** ending just happens to have ended up being the same letter/sound as the default used to convey plural in ***nouns***.

Comment: The identity of three of the remaining eight inflectional affixes in English (noun plural, noun possessive, and verb 3sPr inflections are all {-Z}) is evidence only of the growing irrelevance of inflection as English changes to a completely analytic language like Vietnamese. Many English dialects around the world don't distinguish  3sPr verbs from 1sP verbs, or singular nouns from plural, depending on context or additional words to be clear. And they often succeed. There is no **Why?** answer, but the fact that it can happen is evidence of the relative power of inflections.

Comment: I am, you are, he is -- the three "persons" (sometimes) have different verb forms.  It just so happens (an "accident" of etymology) that the 3rd person singular forms of many verbs end with "S".  This has nothing to do with the use of "S" to change nouns from singular to plural.

Comment: Careful with "chalk" -- the plural would usually not have an 's'.  Also, have you taken a look at http://ell.stackexchange.com/ -- another great site.

Answer (score 3):

There are six persons in English, but we don't use the second person singular any more. The full present tense conjugation of a regular verb used to follow this pattern: I fall, thou fallest, he/she/it falleth, we fall, you fall, they fall.

In modern English the second person singular disappears and the second person plural is used in its place. Also the ending of the third person singular has changed from -eth to -s, this gives the familiar: I fall, you fall, he/she/it falls, we fall, you fall, they fall.

The plural 's' on nouns, however, is even older than than the third person -s ending of verbs so the two endings are unrelated. See the links below for more history.
http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-plu1.htm

http://www.nativlang.com/middle-english/middle-english-grammar.php

Comment: At what point was the switch made for the verb endings? Do you which country started this movement?

Comment: The verb endings reflect a difference between northern England and southern England: northern England had "(e)s", which gradually beat out southern English "eth". See the map [here](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~kroch/courses/lx310/handouts-09/MiddleEnglishVerb.html). In Shakespeare's plays both forms were used ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Tense_and_number)),

Comment: @SatbirKira It certainly hadn't become universal by the middle of the 17th century because the 1662 Book of Common Prayer still used in some Anglican churches uses the 'th' ending. I suspect that the change was taking place at that time but that it did not become universal until the 18th century.

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment to the asker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346886/why-plural-noun-and-verb-in-singular-form-present-tense-takes-s#comment802863_346886), FumbleFingers answered:

> The two "suffixes" have [completely different origins](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-s), so there isn't really a concept of ***Why?*** in the first place - the third person singular ***verb*** ending just happens to have ended up being the same letter/sound as the default used to convey plural in ***nouns***.

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment to the asker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346886/why-plural-noun-and-verb-in-singular-form-present-tense-takes-s/346936#comment802894_346886), John Lawler answered:

> The identity of three of the remaining eight inflectional affixes in English (noun plural, noun possessive, and verb 3sPr inflections are all {-Z}) is evidence only of the growing irrelevance of inflection as English changes to a completely analytic language like Vietnamese. Many English dialects around the world don't distinguish  3sPr verbs from 1sP verbs, or singular nouns from plural, depending on context or additional words to be clear. And they often succeed. There is no **Why?** answer, but the fact that it can happen is evidence of the relative power of inflections.

Answer (score 0):

In [a comment to the asker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346886/why-plural-noun-and-verb-in-singular-form-present-tense-takes-s/346937#comment802974_346886), Hot Licks answered:

> I am, you are, he is -- the three "persons" (sometimes) have different verb forms.  It just so happens (an "accident" of etymology) that the 3rd person singular forms of many verbs end with "S".  This has nothing to do with the use of "S" to change nouns from singular to plural.