# 's ending in English simple present tense

Tags: etymology, pronouns, present-tense, grammatical-case, agreement

I was wondering whether someone would be able to explain the origin of the -s form as used to bind  a predicate with a third person subject  (he,she,it) to express a "simple " present sentence as in he has breakfast. Is there any etymologic hint to explain it.

If it results from a language evolution what is the need for adopting such a flexion as  it doesn't seem to ring a meaningful bell in the mind of people (save for morphological habit) or does it mean it signals the binding of a predicate to a subject that is by definition absent and not in a position to assert the validity of the binding?

Comment: Further in the past, English had more elaborate conjugation:  I look, thou lookest, he looketh, and so on.  Find this in Shakespeare, for example.  Many languages have such conjugations for verbs: and you think it is useless only because it is not found in your native language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why plural noun and verb in singular form, present tense takes 's'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346886/why-plural-noun-and-verb-in-singular-form-present-tense-takes-s) (The question is hard to understand but the top answer should be useful.)

Comment: As it finally happened, the (roughly Northern) -th suffix gave way to the (roughly Southern) -s suffix in standard English when most of the recorded talk (e.g, literature) took place in the South of England (e.g, London).

Comment: @JohnLawler You might want to check whether *-eth* was more southern rather than northern.  See for example https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Middle_English_verbs#The_present

Comment: I said "roughly". The original -s came from Norse, and the -th was English. But folks kept moving around and their dialects kept changing.